# How to get specific elements from a list of DOM objects that have been loaded from an external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a way to get specific DOM elements by id (and/or class) from an array of DOM elements that has been created using jQuery parseHTML function?

*I am not looking for document.getElementByID() as it gets elements from the current page.*

**Background:**

I have to create a pdf from a web page that has dynamic content. in order to keep the pdf look consistent, I have created an html template with fixed-sized elements that have specific ids.

I would like to write a java script code that:

1 - loads the contents of the template page,

2 - grabs specific s from the current page (that have specific id's) and

3 - inserts these specific s into the target areas of the template.

the way I am doing this is:

read the template file using AJAX asynch functions and store it into a variable called templ.

then follow a pattern like this:

```
var template = $.parseHTML(templ); //gives an array of DOM elements

//loop through all the children and children of children of template and when I found a match:
{
var a = $('#id_of_div_in_source_page'); //
template[i].children[j].children[k].children[l].innerHTML = a.html();
}
```

finally export 'template' into html.

I am looking for way to skip the whole looping process.

---

p.s. it is a little bit different that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592203/how-to-load-html-into-a-skin-that-has-also-been-loaded-from-an-external-html-f) because I have to do it for multiple elements.

Comment: when you say "dynamic" what do you mean? Where is the data actually coming from? A database, the user, json?

Comment: data comes from a data base on page load. but I have to put it in a template or skin because i dont want the user's screen size, orientation, etc, change the way the pdf looks.

Comment: @somdow please read above

Comment: Give the element an ID and do `$(template).find('#id')`

Comment: @adeneo lets say I have var b = $(template).find('#id'), how do I set the contents of b?

Comment: @adeneo, never mind! b.html('something') !!

Comment: @adeno, sorry, Im a JS, JQ Noob! Do you know how to convert template back to html string? (after modifying its contents)

Comment: Sure, `$(template).get(0).outerHTML`

Comment: Didn't work. It returned undefined on get(0). Let me try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was based on @adneo's comment. I looped through all the elements and called outerHTML and concatenated it into a string:

```
var outputHTML = "";
for(var j = 0; j < template.length; j++)
{
   var temp = $(template).get(j).outerHTML; //temp is undefined for empty nodes!
   if(temp !== undefined)
   {
      outputHTML += temp;
   }
}
```

Thanks to Adeneo.